# How to using dropdown element change option in cq dialog dynamically?

Tags: xml, components, aem

I want to wrote an AEM component where I would like to add some elements to my side. In one component I want to add three difference option, and I would like to change this option dynamically.

Actually I try to add some part of code to my cq_dilog.xml, but the problem is that I have an three dropdown options to chose but I can't change trigger element.

```
<jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" jcr:title="Text"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
             sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <title jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                           fieldLabel="Trigger"
                           sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                           filedDescription="URL to the page you will linked to."
                            name="./title"/>
                    <type
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
                            fieldLabel="Type" name="./type"
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <option1 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Download" />
                            <option2 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Link" />
                            <option3 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Add" />
                        </items>
                    </type>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I got your point. Would you like to dynamically show/hide some fields in the dialog based on the selected option or woould you rather like to hava a dynamic option list, so that you have different options on different pages?

Comment: hmm basically Your first argu is more interesting. I want to have some dynamicly show fileds in the dialog based on selected dropdown option. For example I chose in dropdown add and I have a place to add link, in dropdown I chose downlad I can connect to this component only download option. This should be a trigger component ( button).

Answer (score 7):

I see in your example that you are mixing older Coral2 widgets (granite/ui/components/foundation/..) with newer Coral3 widgets (granite/ui/components/**coral**/foundation/..).

The article provided by Oliver is useful if you're using Coral2 but consider migrating completely to Coral3 ([more info here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/legacy/coral2/migration.html)), in which case there is a different but in my opinion better and clearer system. The concept is the same but the implementation has changed.

Here is the implementation in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:granite="http://www.adobe.com/jcr/granite/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Properties"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/fixedcolumns">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <text
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
                        fieldLabel="Text"
                        name="./text"/>
                    <dropdown
                        granite:class="cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide"
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/select"
                        fieldLabel="Dropdown"
                        name="./dropdown">
                        <granite:data
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-target=".option-showhide-target"/>
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <no-option
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="No option"
                                value="no-option"/>
                            <option
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="Option"
                                value="option"/>
                        </items>
                    </dropdown>
                    <dynamic-option
                        granite:class="hide option-showhide-target"
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/checkbox"
                        text="Dynamic option">
                        <granite:data
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            showhidetargetvalue="option"/>
                    </dynamic-option>
                </items>
            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Here are the important parts:

1. The granite:class property of the dropdown node enables the dynmic show/hide functionality
2. The `cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-target` property of the `granite:data` node under the `dropdown` node defines the custom class responsible for toggling the dynamic fields (here I used `.option-showhide-target`, but you could call it anything you want)
3. The `granite:class` of the target node (`dynamic-option` in our case) tells our field what class (the custom class from step 2) to bind its show/hide behaviour to.
4. The `showhidetargetvalue` property of the `granite:data` node under our target node defines which item in the dropdown (based on the value property) will toggle the show/hide behaviour.

Here is a screenshot of the structure in CRXDE:

[image]

And here is a GIF of the result:
[image]

Comment: Thank You I use aem version 6.2, maybe the is a reason  that wen I use Option on the dropdown I don' have a checkbox visible. Now I have a new idea how to roslove my problem. I want to add an value on my three option and use htl code to chceck witch is selected. For all elements i use the same pathbrowser

Comment: Great answer but be carefully if using it.  If the user were to select "Option", check the "Dynamic option" checkbox and then change the dropdown to "No option" the checkbox is hidden but remains checked.  In your sling model you may want to treat this scenario the same as if it had remained unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a working example available in the wcm core implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/list/v1/list/_cq_dialog/.content.xml).

And Adobe even has a step by step description for dynamic [touch ui dialogs](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/dynamic_touchui.html). Search for showhidetargetvalue  to find the interesting part.

HTH.

Comment: Thx but in this example on GitHub when I change any option on dropdown list nothing was change in cq_dialog

Comment: If you have a AEM with we-retail installed, have a look at the list component. It is working there.